# Sbt build hangs on random stages

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I have a multi-project sbt build that hangs on different stages of its executions (either after one or multiple modules are compiled).

**I would appreciate any input on possible reason of its hanging.**

To give a context this **build contains three modules**:

- *frontend*: scala.js module
- *backend*: web server in akka-http
- *model*: shared code of models and json serializers

`build.sbt` file:

```
name := "my-project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

lazy val `my-project` = (project in file(".")).aggregate(backend, frontend, modelJvm, modelJs)

lazy val backend =
  (project in file("backend"))
    .dependsOn(modelJvm)
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "0.5.1",
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.11"
      ),
      resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
        val f1 = (fastOptJS in Compile in frontend).value
        val f2 = (packageScalaJSLauncher in Compile in frontend).value
        Seq(f1.data, f2.data)
      }.taskValue,
      watchSources ++= (watchSources in frontend).value
    )

lazy val frontend =
  (project in file("frontend"))
    .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
    .settings(
      scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true,
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.6.7",
        "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.2"
      )
    )
    .dependsOn(modelJs)

lazy val model = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("model"))
                  .settings(
                     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                       "com.lihaoyi" %%% "upickle" % "0.5.1"
                     )
                  )

lazy val modelJs = model.js
lazy val modelJvm = model.jvm
```

`plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.22")

addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")
```

`build.properties`:

```
sbt.version = 1.1.0
```

Build process sample:

```
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources to .../backend/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to ...frontend/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[warn] there was one deprecation warning (since 0.6.20); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Done compiling.
```

After that sbt is not responding. I see in task manager and jvisualvm that java process corresponding to this build consumes all allocated to it memory (Xmx value).

Any suggestions/advices are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that it's actually hanging, and not just taking a very long time?  Even before you mentioned Xmx, my guess was that the linker was running out of memory, and when the linker hits that limit it can run *really* slowly.  How much memory have you allocated?  Scala.js can require quite a bit for good compile/link performance...

Comment: I tried multiple options with -Xmx1G and -mem 3000. As per libvisualvm I hit those in 5-10 minutes. Entire project is < 30 files long so I was not expecting this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it turned out not to be a memory issue but a library issue. In this build **`upickle`** library was used for json serialization in shared module:

```
"com.lihaoyi" %%% "upickle" % "0.5.1"
```

As per usage it looks like this library uses *macro* to generate serialization/deserialization mechanisms. Once I migrated to

```
"com.github.benhutchison" %%% "prickle" % "1.1.13"
```

build was able to complete within seconds without much memory - around `-Xmx1G`. I will try to reduce example and will submit an issue to github.

Answer (score 1):

Scala.js is extremely memory hungry, as a trade-off against compilation time. 1GB is definitely not enough for a typical project.

I recommend at least `-Xmx3G` when starting sbt, 4G if you can afford it.

Note that the amount of source files directly in your project is not very elegant. All your transitive dependencies count towards the total memory used, as they need to be loaded in memory to be linked together with your project.

Comment: I actually tried that. As per jvisualvm all memory was consumed within 10 minutes. Moreover if I execute `fastOptJS` separately for scala.js module, it is completed within seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Setting log level to debug could possibly help, like

```
logLevel := Level.Debug
```

as described [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-set-sbt-logging-level-build.sbt/), for example